# Many global assumptions

Tags: assumptions

I will do some calculations with probability distribution p[t] - which is a vector and each term corresponds to a probability of some event. Accordingly the sum over the terms in p[t] has to be one, for all times t.
I have tried to implement it in such a way

```
p[t_] := {p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]}; 
$Assumptions = Total[p[_]] == 1;
$Assumptions = p[_] \[Element] PositiveReals
```

But it doesn't work, as

```
In[275]:= Simplify[Total[p[_]]]

Out[275]= p0[_] + p1[_] + p2[_] + p3[_]


In[276]:= Simplify[Total[p[7]]]

Out[276]= p0[7] + p1[7] + p2[7] + p3[7]
```

And I would expect 1 as the output, in both cases.
Thanks the comments I know that the problem is the second assumption, which "delate" the first one.
How can I include many global assumptions in the different parts of my notebook (as I have many assumptions concerning different things which are defined at different places)?

Comment: `Refine[Total[p[7]], Total[p[_]] == 1]` works for me and gives 1. Also for `Simplify`.

Comment: But how can I set Total[p[_]] = 1 everywhere, in the whole notebook?

Comment: I checked with fresh starded Mathematica, all your commands work for me and give 1 as expected.

Comment: I have used Clear["Global`*"] and run it once again and have still the same problem. I have Mathematica 12.0.0

Comment: `Clear["Global`*"]` does not remove `$Assumptions`. Save your nb and Quit Kernel, then start Local Kernel again, and check commands. I did this and all is working.

Comment: I have quit the kernel and it still does not work.

Comment: `Quit[]`. Then `p[t_] := {p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]};`, `$Assumptions = Total[p[_]] == 1;`, `Simplify[Total[p[_]]]` gives 1, `Simplify[Total[p[7]]]` also gives 1. Try to close Mathematica, start it again afresh and do these commands. If does not work, sorry, I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, now I see what was the problem. Under `$Assumptions = Total[p[_]] == 1` I had  `$Assumptions = x \[Element] PositiveReals` ... Does the second `$Assumptions` delate the first one? How one can then do it? I don't want to specify everything in single `$Assumptions` as I have many global assumptions which correspond to quite different things which I define at different places in my notebook...

Comment: In several `$Assumptions` last wins (reorder your `$Assumptions` and see the result), so either combine all-in-one, or use `Block[{$Assumptions=...},<commands using these $Assumptions>]`, see help page for `$Assumptions`.

Comment: Hm, this is rather inconvenient. There is no other way around?

Comment: Edit your question and add info that you have several `$Assumptions`, probably someone more experienced in Mathematica can answer, but I have no more to advice, sorry.

Comment: Ok, many thanks

Comment: I suggest you read a [tutorial on patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html). Your `p[_]`  matches too widely for what you want.

Comment: What I mean is that `Refine[p0[x] + p1[y] + p2[z] + p3[w], Total[p[_]] == 1]` simplifies to `1` as well. You need to constrain the arguments of the different components of `p` to be equal before simplifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append new assumptions to `$Assumptions` using [`AppendTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppendTo.html):

```
p[t_] := {p0[t], p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]}; 

$Assumptions = {Total[p[_]] == 1};
AppendTo[$Assumptions , p[_] ∈ PositiveReals];

Simplify[Total[p[_]]]
```

> 1

```
Simplify[Total[p[7]]]
```

> 1